# Is there a way to combine re-tokenize several tokens into one using TokensRegex?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I want to combine consecutive tokens with the same named entity annotation (say, STANFORD UNIVERSITY, where both tokens "stanford" and "university" have NE "ORGANIZATION") into a single token, so that I just have "STANFORD UNIVERSITY" with NE "ORGANIZATION". Is there a way to do that with tokens regex?

So, this really is a two-part question:

1) How would you write the pattern for an unbroken sequence of tokens with the same NER?

2) How would you write the action to combine captured tokens into one (basically, do the opposite of the Split function)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `entitymentions` annotator, which will do this for you and extract full entities from the text.

sample code:

```
package edu.stanford.nlp.examples;

import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;

import java.util.*;

public class EntityMentionsExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Annotation document =
        new Annotation("John Smith visted Los Angeles on Tuesday.");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,entitymentions");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    pipeline.annotate(document);

    for (CoreMap entityMention : document.get(CoreAnnotations.MentionsAnnotation.class)) {
      System.out.println(entityMention);
    }
  }
}
```